# Design a simple 2D sliding window on a 6 by 6 matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, parallel-processing, sliding

Background:

I have a 6 by 6 matrix. I need to update the values among the grid points by sliding a 3 by 3 window according to these steps:

[image]

(1) The first sliding window is: treat `x8` as centre and I have `w1 = {x1, x2, x3, x7, x8, x9, x13, x14, x15}`.

(2) The values of these 9 points are updated by adding 1 to each of the grid point.

(3) Move to next window: treat `x9` as a centre and I have `w2 = {x2, x3, x4, x8, x9, x10, x14, x15, x16}`. The values of these grid points are updated again by adding 1 to each of them. **Note that I use the original values of `x2, x8 and x14` instead of updated values in step 2.**

(4) The process continues and I will have 16 windows / sets of 9-point data.

---

My problem is that:

(5) Some intersecting points, says, `x8` is overlapped by 4 windows. Then I want to pick up the `x8` from 4 windows and add them together, followed by dividing by 4 (averaging).

(6) Some intersecting points, says, `x15` is indeed overlapped by 9 windows. Again, I would like to obtain an average among these 9 values of `x15`.

(7) After these updates, I would like to have a updated 6 by 6 matrix to store the result.

---

My thought:

(1) Apply the "adding one" on each window, `w1, w2, ..., w16`.

(2) Pick up the common values among the windows:

if `x8` is intersected by 4 times, add those `x8` and divided by 4;

if `x15` is intersected by 9 times, add those `x15` and divided by 9.

---

Need help:

I want to write my code in matlab. So, I plan to use `ismember` to extract the common values among the windows but it seems that `ismember` cannot have multiple inputs. May I know if there are any neat ways in `matlab` to achieve this purpose?

Since I am a newbie to `matlab`, a more detailed codes will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand your operation. If the point `x15` (or any other), contain the value `v` and is overlapped by `n=9` windows, after your operations you will average `v_avg=(n*v+n*1)/n`, which is simply `=v+1`. You are going to add `1` to each point of your grid, you don't need a sliding window for that.

Comment: @Hoki Indeed the operation is not simply adding 1 to each of the grid. It is a little bit sophisticated operation on those 9 values. I just try to make things simple.

Comment: ok, then I suggest you look at [`conv2`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conv2.html). It can help with a lot of "sliding window" problems. Otherwise try a simple approach with `loops`, post your code in the question (and the desired result). It can help understanding what you really want to do.